# MATLAB: How to create a uniform time vector/timeseries for multivariate signals

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, sensors

I have a series of signals which were sampled at different time lengths and so have different sampling frequencies and sample numbers.

For example, I use a linear motor to measure force at 2, 3 & 4mm/s which naturally gives me running times in a descending order: 38s, 27s, 22s. I also have 2 IMU units with 6 DoF's and an audio sensor recording data in parallel.

I would like to have uniform sampling frequency of 10kHz and a run time of 50 seconds. This being the requirement do I make a time series or a time vector?

Should I interpolate/decimate data first or create a time series/vector first and then rely on the inbuilt interpolation function to synchronize all the channels?

Comment: You could use the `resample()` function to make sure every signal has the same number of samples. https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/resample.html

Comment: Use the resample function to resample each vector to a new rate. Resample  will do the interpolation/decimation for you as the ratio of both operations actually determine the new sampling frequency